# How to perform image recognition when images within a class vary a lot(totally different shapes and apperance)?Are there any papers introducing this?

Tags: deep-learning, image-recognition

We are very familiar with regular image recognition and achived great performance, such as cat-dog recognition. But I come cross a slightly different task, say how to perform image recognition when images within a class vary a lot(totally different shapes and apperance).Take insect recognition for instance,[image]

And the conditions is we treat the images of a insect in different life cycles as a class.
Is there any way can solve this, like some hierarchical ways?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever tried transfer learning and didn't get promising results?

Comment: Yes, I've tried transfer and fine-tuning on my dataset, and it didn't perform well.